# How to solve $3y\cos(\theta) - 2x\sin(\theta) = 5 \sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$?

Tags: calculus, optimization

> How to solve $3y\cos(\theta) - 2x\sin(\theta) = 5 \sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$?

I am optimizing a function where I need to solve the above equation for $\theta$. What is the best way to do this? I don't know if there are any obvious trigonometric identities to use here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider the general equation $$A\cos(\theta) +B\sin(\theta) +C \sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)=0$$ to be solved for $\theta$; you could use the tangent half-angle substitution $t=\tan(\frac \theta 2$). This leads to a quartic polynomial $$A t^4-2( B- C)t^3 -2  (B+C)t-A=0$$ which can be solved explicitely with radicals (not the most pleasant but doable).

**Edit**

What you could also do is to extract, say, $\cos(\theta)$ from the equation; this leads to $$\cos(\theta)=-\frac{B \sin(\theta)}{A+C \sin(\theta)}$$ and now use $\cos^2(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta)=1$. Setting $x=\sin(\theta)$, this leads to the quartic $$C^2 x^4+2 A C x^3+ \left(A^2+B^2\right)x^2-1=0$$ Written as above, what is nice is that, whatever coefficients $A,B,C$ could be, $f(0)=-1$; so we are (almost) sure to hit a positive root. Starting Newton method with $x_0=0$ will give as first iterate $x_1=\frac{1}{A^2+B^2}$.